# How to add fields in the serializer?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

MODELS:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Person (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    card_tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    extra = models.TextField()
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

SERIALIZER:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'surname', 'card_tag', 'extra']
```

QUESTION:

When I do request with POST method I transmit (name, surname, card_tag, extra) in JSON format and token of User in header.

So how can I:
1) get 'organization' by user (token)

2) and add 'organization' to the PersonSerializer when it will save given data to the database

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
def get_organization(self):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    return Organization.objects.filter(user=user).first()

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'surname', 'card_tag', 'extra']

    def create(self, kw):
        return Person.objects.create(organization=get_organization(self), **kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of something very similar this [in the DRF Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users). Basically you need to set this data inside the `perform_create` method of a view using the [`CreateModelMixin`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) mixin.

In your case:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    organization = self.request.user.organization_set.all().first()
    serializer.save(organization=organization)
```

Keep in mind that you might get more than one organization for each user. If you don't want that, you'd better use a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: thanks)) I gonna change ForeignKey to OneToOneField . I use method get_organization(self). so which one is better to use ? and what's difference with my answer (below)  Thanks  again!

Comment: Your answer is using `create` while mine uses `perform_create`. See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18 for the difference.